# How to retrieve data from two tables whose column names are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to retrieve data from two tables whose column names are the same?

Comment: i hv to use where clause.
means i hv to take userid from usertable and use it to get data from table1 and table2 whose column names are same.both tables contains userid column.now how i can apply where clause

Comment: As I said : use aliases. You accepted an answer that doesn't even fit what you describe above.

Comment: Based on the question and OP's comment, the selected answer is completely different than what the correct answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include rows from both tables, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table2
```

Comment: Downvoters: When I started to write the answer there were no comment explaining what exactly the OP wants. As you can see, I started my answer with "If...". It's funny that I get downvotes because the OP decided to accept my answer :)

Comment: +1 to get you out of the hole. I understand. Additionally a rightfully accepted answer shouldn't have a negative number associated.

Answer (score 3):

Use aliases, ie.

```
select table1.field as table1field, table2.field as table2field from table1 
join table2 on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the columns (not Union), set alias for each column for one of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias

```
select a.col_name, b.col_name from table1 a, from table2 b
where a.userid =b.userid  // condition as per your comments in question
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alias names ?? :-)

```
SELECT t1.col1 as name1 , t2.col1 as name2 from table1 t1, table2 t2
```